# Multiple Find Query in single database connection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, performance, eloquent

Trying to enhance performance in Laravel query. Making multiple find operations on a single model, withing a loop, but trying to make it use a single database connection instance.

```php
$departments = [];

foreach ($this->departments_only as $department) {
    array_push($departments, Department::find($department));
}

return $departments;
```

No error. But just want a better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the `departments_only` is array of ids, so you can use `whereIn`

```
$departments = Department::whereIn('id', $this->departments_only)->get();
```

This will return collection of `departments`.

Comment: Works Fine. Thanks loads

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, I use this library [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

And do it:

```
$myArray = [1,2,3,4];

$result = $this->repository->scopeQuery(function ($query) use ($myArray) {
            return $query
                ->whereIn("departament_id", $myArray);
        })->all();

return $result
```

Or using raw queries and pure Laravel:

```
$myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

$result = DB::table('departments')
                ->selectRaw('departament_id in (?)', $myArray)
                ->get();
```

Comment: ```php  Department::find($this->departments_only);```  works best!

Answer (score 0):

if `$this->departments_only` has only ids in array then you can use

```
Model::whereIn('column','array')->get();
```

For more reference visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Or use DB object as,

```
DB::statement('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN ('"array_of_ids"')');
```